# Is there a number, such that its square is recorded using three ones and a number of zeros?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

For example: 10011, 10010000100, 1110000.

I've been working on this for the past few days but I just can't seem to find a way to crack it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be a multiple of 3, but not a multiple of 9, so would not be a square.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you elaborate just a little bit? I'm not entirely sure how you arrived at this conclusion. I'm sorry if it's totally obvious, it's been a couple of years for me since I've finished math classes.

Comment: If you have a perfect square that is divisible by $3$, it should be divisible by $9$. Indeed, let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. If $3\vert k^2\Rightarrow $ there is $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3a=k^2$. Since $3$ is a prime number, it follows that $3|k$ which means that there is $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k=3b$, thus $k^2=9b^2$ which means $9|k^2$. Now, a divisibility criterion states that a number is divisible by $3$ (respectively ($9$) if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$ (or $9$). Your numbers have the sum of their digits $3$ which is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$, so they can't be squares.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much!